# @DateTimeFormat pattern or jackson date-format in spring mvc not working

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC app. I have the following pattern set to my entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Test {
    @CreationTimestamp
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
    private Timestamp createdTime;
```

In my `application.property` I have this line:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa
```

I am showing the date from thymeleaf as follows:

```html
<tr th:each="problem : ${test}">
  <td th:text="${problem.id}" />
  <td th:text="${problem.createdTime}" />
  ...
</tr>
```

But it is showing this format from html and on Postgresql select regardless of pattern specified in `@Datetimeformat` annotation:

```
2021-06-26 16:27:29.105
```

I want datetime to be shown in this format from html:

```
2021-06-26 04:27:29 PM
```

How can I do this? It would be better if I could just change it from the application.property file since I have many other Timestamp columns and I don't want to change each file. Thank you.

Comment: can you share a Github link for a sample? So that I can debug it easily in my local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read the dateTime format from the `application.properties` file and pass that as the date format to the Thymeleaf's `#dates` util, so you don't need to do any changes in entity level and can control the DateTime parse through single place.

```
<tr th:each="problem : ${test}">
  <td th:text="${problem.id}" />
  <td th:text="${#dates.format(problem.createdTime,@environment.getProperty('spring.jackson.date-format'))}" />
  ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using Thymeleaf template engine, so try this:

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(problem.createdTime,'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa'}" />
```